# RabbitMq: Messages are not appearing in a RabbitMq queue when adding DLX or making it as Durable

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, dead-letter, dlx

I have queue configured in my RabbitMq server which is bound to default exchange. The queue name is "MobileBankingResponse". It worked as expected, before I have configured DLX/DLQ for it. Here is the code that describes how I have configured DLX/DLQ.

```
        channel = connection.CreateModel();

        channel.ExchangeDeclare(ApplicationSettings.Instance.MqName + "DLX", ExchangeType.Fanout);

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: ApplicationSettings.Instance.MqName + "DLQ",
            durable: false,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false,
            arguments: null);

        channel.QueueBind(queue: ApplicationSettings.Instance.MqName + "DLQ",
            exchange: ApplicationSettings.Instance.MqName + "DLX",
            routingKey: "");

        var queueArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "x-dead-letter-exchange", ApplicationSettings.Instance.MqName + "DLX" }
        };

        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: ApplicationSettings.Instance.MqName, 
            durable: false, 
            exclusive: false, 
            autoDelete: false, 
            arguments: queueArgs);
```

Basically what happens is the sender of a message is successfully publishing the message to queue, but it does not appear in the queue.

Here is the method for publishing the message.

```
public ResponseBase SendMessage(string message, string callType, string queueName, IConfiguration configuration)

{

    var response = new ResponseBase() { ResponseStatusCode = default};

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.UserName = configuration["MqLogin"];
    factory.Password = configuration["MqPassword"];
    factory.VirtualHost = "/";
    factory.HostName = configuration["MqLink"];
    factory.Port =int.Parse(configuration["MqPort"]);

    try
    {
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName,
                           durable: false,
                           exclusive: false,
                           autoDelete: false,
                           arguments: null);

            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            Dictionary<string, object> headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            headers.Add(configuration["MqHeaderName"], callType);

            IBasicProperties basicProperties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            basicProperties.Headers = headers;

            channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                           routingKey: queueName,
                           basicProperties: basicProperties,
                           body: body);
        }

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
         return new ResponseBase() { ResponseStatusCode = 1, ResponseMessage = "Connection lost" };
    }
}
```

After noticing the issue, I have removed DLX from the queue and it started working as expected again. Continuing further I have noticed that the issue is not only the DLX, making the queue as durable is also blocking the messages. See screenshot below.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l7s4.png)

Comment: The reason was not giving argument (x-dead-letter-exchange) from sender side when declaring queue.